# Intersection of (relativized/preimage) measure 0 with every hyperarithmetic perfect set

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, recursive-ordinals

Given a perfect tree $T$ on $2^{<\omega}$ viewed as a function from $2^{<\omega}$ to $2^{<\omega}$ define the measure of a subset of $[T]$ to be the measure of it's preimage under the usual measure on $2^{\omega}$.

Suppose $X \subset 2^{\omega}$ is a $\Delta^1_1$ class (i.e. lightface Borel)  and for every hyperarithmetic perfect tree $T$ $X \cap [T]$ has measure $0$ as a subset of $T$ (i.e., it's preimage has measure 0).  Is $X$ necessarily countable?  (this is true if we replace hyperarithmetic with computable in $\mathcal{O}$ -- see below).

More generally, for a pointclass  $\Gamma \subset P(2^{\omega})$ (e.g. the $\Sigma^0_n$ classes in $2^\omega$)  and a class of sets $\Lambda \subset P(\omega)$ (e.g.the $\Sigma^0_n$ subsets of $\omega$) say that $\Gamma$ has the measure 0 perfection property relative to $\Lambda$ if for all  $X \in \Gamma$ if $X \cap [T]$ has measure $0$ relative to $T$ for all perfect trees $T \in \Lambda$ then $X$ is countable.

For what nice pairs $\Gamma, \Lambda$ does the measure 0 perfection property hold?

It's clearly true that the $\Pi^0_1$ pointclass has the measure 0 perfection property with respect to the $\Delta^0_2$ sets (in the cantor space every $\Pi^0_1$ class is equal to $[T]$ for some $\Delta^0_2$  $T$).  Do the $\Pi^0_2$ classes have it with respect to the $\Delta^0_3$ sets? Arithmetic sets?  What about $\Pi^0_\omega$ classes?

Note that this notion isn't totally trivial since the $\Sigma^1_1$ pointclass has the measure 0 perfection property with respect to the sets computable from Kleene's O since if $X$ is $\Sigma^1_1$ then $X$ contains a perfect set iff it contains $[T]$ for a perfect tree $T$ computable in $O$ and as every boldface $\Sigma^1_1$ set has the perfect set property it follows that if $X$ is uncountable then there is a perfect tree $T$ computable in O with $[T] \subset X$.

Comment: Note that, the existence of a non-empty $\Pi^0_2$ class  with no hyperarithmetic member gives an example of a perfect set (any isolated branch would be of hyperarithmetic degree) where we can't hope to find any hyperarithmetic perfect tree  with []⊂. The question is if we can make sure  has non-zero measure on [].

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Let $X$ be any nonempty $\Delta^1_1$ set without hyperarithmetic member. Now suppose that $T$ is a $\Delta^1_1$-perfect tree. So there is a hyperarithmetic homeomorphism $f:[T]\to 2^{\omega}$. Then $X\cap[T]$ is also a $\Delta^1_1$ set. Since $f$ is a hyperarithmetic homeomorphism, $f(X\cap[T])$ is a $\Delta^1_1$ set without a hyperarithmetic member. By a theorem of Sacks, which says that every non-null $\Delta^1_1$ set has a hyperarithmetic member, $f(X\cap[T])$ must be null.